# CAReportingClient.mm:532 Attempted to remove a reporter not created by this client

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, warnings, core-audio

After I've updated my iPhone to iOS 17 I started seeing a message being printed in Xcode. In bursts of a few or once every seconds.

I'm listening to `CLLocationManager` updates but don't do much with it yet.  When I disable this, I got only a few of these messages right after app startup.

I'm showing the live camera feed on screen using an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` that's used in SwiftUI code using `UIViewRepresentable`.

```
CAReportingClient.mm:532 Attempted to remove a reporter not created by this client { careporter_id=4.569.845.202.954 }
CAReportingClient.mm:532 Attempted to remove a reporter not created by this client { careporter_id=4.569.845.202.955 }
CAReportingClient.mm:532 Attempted to remove a reporter not created by this client { careporter_id=4.569.845.202.956 }
CAReportingClient.mm:532 Attempted to remove a reporter not created by this client { careporter_id=4.569.845.202.957 }
```

Does anyone knows what might be the cause?

Comment: I think this is related to the CarPlay connection. Do you use the Carplay in your project?

Comment: @AdrianWitaszak No CarPlay is involved.

Comment: I get those messages when using `CHHapticEngine`